# Is window.document assumed when using a document object?

Tags: javascript, window, document

Looking at w3schools JavaScript reference regarding [the window object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp), the document object seem to be a property of it. Although, as we know, the document object doesn't require any explicit `window.document`, but only `document`. Having checked if they are different or not, I used this piece of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function()
        {           
            alert("Using window.document: " + window.document.images.length);
            alert("Using document: " + document.images.length);
        };
</script>
<img id="1" src="/images/some_pic.gif" />
<img id="2" src="/images/some_other_pic.gif" />
```

...showing that both methods print out `2` (the number of images in the document). This made me curious about a couple of things I couldn't find answers to elsewhere:

1. Is one method better than the other? Despite having used `document` my entire time, I find `window.document` more logical. Although other than that, will there be any other gain from using one or another?
2. Assuming that it's the same thing, is this type of "syntax" (whereas a member can be referred to immediately as a shortcut) called something? Can it be logically explained somehow (like, is `document` a reference to `window.document`?
3. Are these types of things seen anywhere else in the language? Or does it only apply to the document object?

Comment: All properties of the `window` object are global variables, so as such you can access them as regular variables without the `window`. However, you can define a local `document` variable that references something else, so in that case you'd need to be explicit by using `window.document`... unless of course `window` has also been redefined locally.

Comment: @cookie monster Oh, that does make sense. But in that case, why even bother using window explicitly (apart from the cases where you have a variable with the same name, which isn't that common nor smart)? And is this special case only meant for the window object?

Thank you for the response

Comment: The local definition issue would be the only reason, though it's better to simply not define local variables that conflict with commonly used globals. The `window` object is the only case where you have access to the object that holds the variables, so in that sense, it's a special case. It is possible to redefine (shadow) a local variable in a more deeply nested variable scope, but in that case it's simply impossible to reach around the deeper one to get the outer one. The global object is the only place where you can do that.

Comment: @cookie monster Oh, I see then. The methods seem global too, which explains the alert-function (which I just saw). Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything attached to `window` as a property can be accessed without `window.` in front of it. Every JavaScript environment has a "global namespace". `window` is the global namespace in the browser. If you were writing JavaScript in node.js then an object called `global` is the global namespace.

If you declare a variable without the `var` keyword then that variable becomes "global". Maybe you already knew this, but what you may not know is that your variable actually became a property of `window`.

```
function doSomething() {
    var inScope = "I am only accessible within the doSomething function.";
    notInScope = "I am a global variable which means you can access me at window.notInScope.";
}
```

Also, even if you do use `var` but it's not wrapped in anything that would limit its scope then it also becomes a global variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isGlobal = "This variable is global even though we used 'var' because it was declared in the root/global scope.";
</script>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/a5fanTIJRpxxjjqgrr4D?p=info

Comment: Thanks for the extended response. This basically sums most of it up as well - it does exist in other contexts (such as with `global`) and it has to with the global namespace. The only thing not as covered is about what's better, but that can be figured out from this. In all, I guess I'm a bit confused by the fact that a class is counted as a "global namespace", after having worked with languages such as C++ (where you explicitly use `::` to refer to it).

Comment: There is no "better" :) It's just syntactic sugar that you're able to reference the global namespace without explicitly calling `window.prop`. If your coming from languages like that then try to shed your idea of a "namespace". In JS, a namespace is just something that limits scope (usually an object); since `window` is the root object everything attaches to, it is the global namespace.

Comment: I see now (a bit different from using `namespace`, but I might get used to the variant of the term). Thanks again for your help!

Comment: No problem. Yeah, if you ever see [code like this](https://gist.github.com/chevex/74e6ac263bfc190664ca) (which you probably already have) I've heard that called "namespacing" a lot, even though there isn't actually any specific thing you can point to and say "that's a namespace". It's just namespacing the code inside it so you can safely use the dollar sign when doing jQuery even if another library is already using it for something else. It's just a closure that limits the scope of everything inside it but "namespacing" is a common term for encapsulating code like that.

Comment: Thanks for making it more clear. The concept of namespaces seems to be equivalent, which really is all that matters. I think I've seen some of the code before, but not until now have I been able to fully understand it. Thanks again :)